# How to disable or readonly lookup field in standard page

Tags: lookup, validation-rule, field-level-security

EDIT:

On a standard page. NOT using VF page

Is it possible to write a validation rule or any approach to make a field disabled once the user save?

I have a page with couple of fields including lookup and once the user save the record I like to prevent user from changing the lookup fields.

Comment: On a standard page or Visualforce page?

Comment: on a standard page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a validation rule that uses ISCHANGED to compare the values of the lookup fields to their previous values. If the user is attempting to change any of the lookups, the rule will throw an error:

```
OR(
  ISCHANGED(Lookup_1__c),
  ISCHANGED(Lookup_2__c),
  ISCHANGED(Lookup_3__c),
  ISCHANGED(Lookup_4__c)
)
```

Comment: got it and its one way to approach the problem but why not just directly work on validatin rule ischanged? instead of adding a field (checkbox) and check against it?, can you post the code how you will check the ischanged in validatin rule

Comment: Because validation rules are applied upon creation and edit of records. You need a flag so the rule knows contextually if it should apply the rule...

Comment: you have said validation rules are applied upon creation and deletion of records but will this also apply editing and updating the existing records?

Comment: @AbuHamzah Actually I was wrong - ISCHANGED isn't enforced on creation, I just tested it...I'll update my answer. Thanks for keeping me honest :)

Comment: @AbuHamzah Validation rules do **not** apply on delete.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I accidentally said "creation and delete" in my first comment instead of "creation and edit," that was my fault for the mixup

Comment: okay thanks, so first off; I have to create a field called let say `lookupfieldslocked` and set that to to false and from my trigger i make that fields set to `true` and create a validation rule as `OR(
  ISCHANGED(Lookup_1__c)' but where I'm checking the `lookupfieldslocked`

Comment: No, as explained in the comments, you don't need a flag, I was mistaken. Just use the above formula in a validation rule.

Comment: @Brian: I'm bit confused now and i see the validation rule you checking with `Lookup_1__c, Lookup_2__c ....` but where you checking to see the previous value in the validation rule? am I missing something

Comment: The rule will not allow anyone to save the record if they try to change the values of the lookup fields. They can only be set upon creation (when they save).