# id value of incorrect type

Tags: apex

Coud you please suggest appropriate solution to the following error.

> Error: Apex trigger PreventTaskOwnerChangeTrigger caused an unexpected
>   exception, contact your administrator: PreventTaskOwnerChangeTrigger:
>   data changed by trigger for field Account: id value of incorrect type:
>   0051400000BOJxdAAH

Comment: Can you post the code of your trigger too ?

Answer (score 6):

Its tough to specify exactly without your code, but from the error, it seems you are trying to set a lookup field that is expecting and Account ID with a user ID.

The 3 digit prefix for the account object is **'001'**, you are trying to set a value that is expecting an account Id with a User Id.  You can tell this because the 3 digit prefix for the user object is **'005'**.

Comment: Salesforce psychic....Chris is so good that he's fixin triggers without even seeing them ;)

Comment: However, given the name of this trigger, it may be more simply accomplished in a validation rule similar to what is discussed in this thread: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77802/how-to-disable-or-readonly-lookup-field-in-standard-page

Comment: +1 @Todd, you are right, it may be we don't need the trigger at all.  (Again tough to say without seeing code)  I was just trying to shed some light on the error that was being received.